# Redis NOAUTH error - despite disabling auth in my redis.conf file

Tags: node.js, redis

I am seeing the following error when running my application locally against a local Redis instance.

```
ReplyError: Ready check failed: NOAUTH Authentication required.
            at JavascriptReplyParser.Parser.returnError (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/node_redis/index.js:193:31)
            at JavascriptReplyParser.run (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/node_redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/javascript.js:135:18)
            at JavascriptReplyParser.execute (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/node_redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/javascript.js:112:10)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/node_redis/index.js:269:27)
            at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
            at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
```

I believe I have disabled authentication by using these lines in the configuration file:

```
# By default protected mode is enabled. You should disable it only if
# you are sure you want clients from other hosts to connect to Redis
# even if no authentication is configured, nor a specific set of interfaces
# are explicitly listed using the "bind" directive.
protected-mode no  #is this correct?
```

and there is no password required:

```
# Require clients to issue AUTH <PASSWORD> before processing any other
# commands.  This might be useful in environments in which you do not trust
# others with access to the host running redis-server.
#
# This should stay commented out for backward compatibility and because most
# people do not need auth (e.g. they run their own servers).
#
# Warning: since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to
# 150k passwords per second against a good box. This means that you should
# use a very strong password otherwise it will be very easy to break.
#
# requirepass foobared
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If you're binding to 0.0.0.0, most probably you've been hacked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anybody runs `CONFIG SET REQUIREPASS [PWD]` in a running redis instance then redis will change its auth config despite conf file. After that, even already connected clients has to set AUTH or they will recieve `NOAUTH Authentication required`.

Try to restart redis and beware for harmful lamers!

Answer (score 6):

On redis-cli, AUTH with the correct password (if your have set password by mistake).
Then set the requirepass to empty. This will resolve the issue.

```
AUTH <old-password>
CONFIG SET REQUIREPASS ""
```

Note : This works only if you know the password (means you have set the password to any of the redis instances). If not, the above solution of restarting redis should work.